# How to trigger a script to reload my page cyclically using a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's my first question here.

I'm working on a project that contain a HTML control to my esp.
The problem is: I have to reload the page after each click to do it once more.

I tried to use `setInterval` with `location.reload` and `mousedown` event...
The problem it creates when I click button down is: the page reloads... But I have to click again each time.

What I need: When I press down the key it sends get method every 10 ms.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Our Robot Game Controller</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="lab1">Left Arm Controls</p>
    <p class="lab2">Wheels Controls</p>
    <p class="lab3">Right Arm Controls</p>
    <div class="AB-1" >
      <button id="up" class="car" >forward</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="AB-2" >
      <button id="do" class="car" >backword</button> <!-- button for pin 11 -->
    </div>
    <div class="AB-3" >
      <button id="ri" class="car">right</button> <!-- button for pin 11 -->
    </div>
    <div class="AB-4" >
      <button id="le" class="car">left</button> <!-- button for pin 11 -->
    </div>
    <div class="Rightarm">
      <div class="AB-5" >
        <button id="up" class="rarm"  >UP</button> 
      </div>
      <div class="AB-6" >
        <button id="do" class="rarm" >Down</button>
      </div>
      <div class="AB-7" >
        <button id="ru" class="rarm">Rotate UP</button>
      </div>
      <div class="AB-8" >
        <button id="rd" class="rarm">Rotate Down</button> 
      </div>
      <div class="AB-9" >
        <button id="ca" class="rarm">collect</button> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftarm">
      <div class="AB-10" >
        <button id="up" class="larm"  >up</button> 
      </div>
      <div class="AB-11" >
        <button id="do" class="larm" >down</button>
      </div>
      <div class="AB-12" >
        <button id="ru" class="larm">Rotate UP</button>
      </div>
      <div class="AB-13" >
        <button id="rd" class="larm">Rotate Down</button>
      </div>
      <div class="AB-14" >
        <button id="ca" class="larm">collect</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var x;
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".car").mousedown(function (){
          x=  setInterval(function() {
            var p = $(this).attr('id');

            $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {car:p}); 
            parent.document.getElementById(p).reload();
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
          },10)});
        $(".rarm").mousedown(function (){
          x=  setInterval(function() {
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
            var p = $(this).attr('id');

            $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {rarm:p}); 
            parent.document.getElementById(p).reload();
          },10)});
        $(".larm").mousedown(function (){
          x=  setInterval(function() {
            var p = $(this).attr('id');

            $.get("http://192.168.4.1:80/", {larm:p}); 
            parent.document.getElementById(p).reload();
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t;
          },10)});
        $(".car").mouseup(function(){
          clearInterval(x);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
          location.reload();
        });
        $(".rarm").mouseup(function(){
          clearInterval(x);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
          location.reload();
        });
        $(".larm").mouseup(function(){
          clearInterval(x);
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
          location.reload();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Making a jsfiddle would help

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: It means create a working example on https://JSFiddle.net. Could be awkward since you've got so many GET requests though, you'd have to simulate/replace them, unless the resources are public and accept CORS requests. At least consider formatting your code here more clearly, it's difficult to read as it is, the indentation is all wrong.

Comment: thanks i will check it out :D

Comment: An Ajax request (your `$.get(...)` ) every 10 ms can only fail... This delay is too short. Then, you should use the Ajax to refresh one "container"... Not the whole page. Reading a little more on Ajax can only help you... ;)

Comment: it did so how long shoud i wait >